# AWS Codebuild Project Using AWS Codecommit

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

Need some help from the community.  I think I almost have it but I can't find documentation showing me how to configure Codebuild project with AWS Codecommit.  Looking for someone to give me a few links that can help or some assistance with my code.

```
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "cb_test_project" {
    name            = var.cb_name
    description     = var.description
    build_timeout   = var.build_timeout
    service_role    = var.cb_service_role
    source_version  = var.branch_name //set to main by default

    artifacts {
        type = "NO_ARTIFACTS"
    }

    environment {
        compute_type                = var.compute_type
        image                       = var.image
        type                        = var.environment_type
        image_pull_credentials_type = "CODEBUILD"
        privileged_mode             = var.privileged_mode

    }


    source {
        
        type      = "CODECOMMIT"
        location  = "my_codecommit_repo"
        buildspec = var.buildspec

    }
    
}
```

My issue is it fails every time I run the build.  Terraform Plan passes all the checks but the apply just errors out. I have no insight into what may be wrong with the syntax but I am hoping i am just missing something simple that will pass the build.

Comment: My best guess is that the service role is missing permissions. CodeBuild should also have `GitPull` permission even though it is not strictly related to AWS.

Comment: Could you add the error to the question above as well?

Answer (score 1):

I am providing the current updated configurations that were used to address this issue.

```
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "cb_test_project" {
    name            = var.cb_name
    description     = var.description
    build_timeout   = var.build_timeout
    service_role    = var.cb_service_role


    artifacts {
        type = "NO_ARTIFACTS"
    }

    environment {
        compute_type                = var.compute_type
        image                       = var.image
        type                        = var.environment_type
        image_pull_credentials_type = "CODEBUILD"
        privileged_mode             = var.privileged_mode

    }


    source {
        
        type            = "CODECOMMIT"
        buildspec       = var.buildspec
        location        = "https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/[repo_name]" #MUST BE THE HTTPS URL!!
        git_clone_depth = 0


    }
    
}
```

As you can see, I had misconfigured the resource and misused other variables. Please visit [GitHub](https://github.com/cwnit/toolkits/blob/master/collections/terraform/aws/aws-codebuild/cb_codecommit.tf) to see a filled-out sample of this.

1. Note you need a Service Role with extensive permissions for this to work
2. Source Location MUST BE the Codecommit HTTPS URL the ssh URL will not work for this. Also, please remove the brackets from the URL they are just there as a placeholder for your repo name.
3. [Review the properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codebuild-project-source.html) so you can understand the values for each one.